# Error in redux-saga : (0,redux Saga.createSagaMiddleWare) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-saga

I try to use saga in my app but occur below error, i cheked several posts about this subject, but can't solve the problem

> (0,redux Saga.createSagaMiddleWare) is not a function

middleware.js:

```
import {createSagaMiddleware} from 'redux-saga'

export const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

export default sagaMiddleware
```

store.js :

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import reducer from '../_reducers'
import sagaMiddleware from './middleware'

export default createStore(reducer,applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));
```

App.js :

```
...

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={ store } >
       ...
 </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App

sagaMiddleware.run(saga)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`createSagaMiddleware` should be a default import. Also, you don't need to do named and default export (in middleware.js).
So, your code would be like this:

```
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

export default sagaMiddleware
```